# Django: Show product detail data using Ajax in modal

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-templates

The usecase of my app is to show a list of furnitures in the homepage. There is quick preview button in all those furnitures which when clicked should show its detail information. I tried to use ajax for that.
If i click on the furniture quick preview button, I get the clicked furniture slug from which I do the query and get that furniture detail information. Upto this, its working and also the modal is shown but could not show the content. How can i now show the content in the modal-body?

Here is what I have tried

```
def ajax_furniture_detail(request):
    furniture_slug = request.GET.get('slug', None)
    qs = Furniture.objects.get(slug=furniture_slug)
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    context = {
    'furniture': model_to_dict(qs),
    'cart': model_to_dict(cart_obj),
    'status': 'ok'
    }
    return JsonResponse(context)

{% block content %}
  {% include 'furnitures/furnitures_home.html'%}
{% endblock content %}
{% block js %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.quick-view-button').click(function() {
          var _this = $(this);
          var slug = _this.attr("data-slug");
          $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/furniture',
            type: "get",
            data: {'slug': slug},
            success: function(data) {
              $('#product-quick-view-modal').modal('show');
              $('#product-quick-view-modal').find('.modal-body').html(data.html);
            },
            error: function(err) {
              console.log('error', err);
            }
          })
        })
    });
  </script>
{% endblock js %}


furnitures_home.html 

{% load static %}
<div class="furnitures" id="content">
    {% for furniture in furnitures %}
      {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row products">{% endif %}
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="image" style="height: 205px;">
            <div class="quick-view-button" data-slug={{ furniture.slug }}>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-quick-view-modal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Quick view</a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="product-quick-view-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>{{furniture.name}}</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--/.modal-dialog-->
</div>
```

Comment: What is your current status? Do you get any error?

Comment: You don't have anything called "html" in the data you're sending in the Ajax response. Do you maybe want to render a template in that view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One neat way to do this is to use a snippet html for product detail and send the product detail html snippet using [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/) and just replace that html snippet in the modal.

```
rendered = render_to_string('product_detail_snippet.html', context, 
                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
return JsonResponse({'product_snippet': rendered})
```

And in the ajax success:

```
$('#product-quick-view-modal').find('.modal-body').html(data.product_snippet);
```

Comment: It is simply a html file, in your case the part of the HTML that shows product detail in modal. Just use the render_to_string and process the HTML in view itself and pass this html string as response to AJAX and finally do the replacing as I have don above.